# SQL sum aggregate function gives wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is given below

> Right answer is Sum = 601,050.00

But SQL sum aggregate function gives me wrong answer that is 5078150.00000

15,000.00 
27,950.00 
 24,750.00 
 11,550.00 
 7,400.00 
 7,500.00  
14,650.00 
 12,500.00  
32,800.00  
35,700.00  
94,100.00  
10,100.00  
19,700.00 
 22,100.00  
35,450.00  
28,050.00  
50,150.00  
69,750.00 
 13,800.00 
 3,600.00  
18,600.00  
2,350.00  
7,200.00  
21,600.00 
 7,700.00  
4,500.00  
2,500.00

```
select  sum(SO_SalesOrder.OrderTotal),l.Name as [Store Name]
    From SO_SalesOrder inner join BASE_Location l on 
    SO_SalesOrder.LocationId = l.LocationId 
    inner join SO_SalesOrder_Line on SO_SalesOrder.SalesOrderId = 
    SO_SalesOrder_Line.SalesOrderId
    inner join BASE_Product on BASE_Product.ProdId = 
    SO_SalesOrder_Line.ProdId
    inner join BASE_Category on BASE_Category.CategoryId = 
    BASE_Product.CategoryId
    where SO_SalesOrder.OrderDate >= '2018-02-01' and 
    SO_SalesOrder.OrderDate <= '2018-02-28' and BASE_Category.Name = '1MHNZ'
    group by l.Name
```

Comment: What's the wrong and what the desired result?

Comment: If you create a minimal example, it could help you find the bug and will also help others to help you.

Comment: We can't run your query, nor do we know what results your expecting, or results you're getting. You need to supply DDL, consumable sample data (that demonstrates the problem), and you're expected results.

Comment: edit your question and add sample data and expected outcome, because we dont know your data

Comment: perhaps you are missing some parenthesis `( )`around the `WHERE` conditions

Comment: ... aww @Igor ? Punctation at the start of your lines :) (. yes aware it's preference but still, not sure you needed to overwrite my edit)

Comment: its actually considered rude to overwrite someones code formatting, but sometimes its just so unreadable that you have to do it... I think there was no need for a second change in formatting after lamu's editing

Comment: @Larnu - the edit was primarily to place the grouped where clauses on the same line so it was easier to see what clauses belonged together. I did not mean any offence, change it back as you see fit. The main problem remains, the question is ambiguous without any input and actual vs expected output.

Comment: The comment was in jest more @Igor. :) I don't mind the grouping of the Clause's, just the punctuation at the start it a personal pet peeve of mine.

Comment: check the question now

Answer (score 1):

There is likely to be a problem with one (or more) of your joins, maybe you have duplicate rows or the joining conditions are not OK.

Remove the `group by l.Name`, the `SUM()` aggregate and see if the returned values for `SO_SalesOrder.OrderTotal` are what you are expecting them to be (you might need to filter with a particular `l.Name` in a `WHERE` clause). It's very likely you will see duplicate amounts, or amounts you are not considering when arriving to the value `601,050.00`.

If so, try joining the tables 1 by 1 and see which ones are making your rows go comando.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your problem depends on the logic of the query.

You have a master-detail relationship between `SO_SalesOrder` and `SO_SalesOrder_line` joined by `SalesOrderId` column.

So if you have three lines in your order you will sum up three times the same `OrderTotal`.

try with something like this:

```
select  sum(SO_SalesOrder.OrderTotal) Total, l.Name as [Store Name]
From SO_SalesOrder 
join BASE_Location l on SO_SalesOrder.LocationId = l.LocationId 
where SO_SalesOrder.OrderDate >= '2018-02-01' and SO_SalesOrder.OrderDate <= '28-02-2018' 
and exists (
    select 0 x
    From SO_SalesOrder_Line 
    join BASE_Product on BASE_Product.ProdId = SO_SalesOrder_Line.ProdId
    join BASE_Category on BASE_Category.CategoryId = BASE_Product.CategoryId
    where BASE_Category.Name = '1MHNZ'
    and SO_SalesOrder_Line.SalesOrderId = SO_SalesOrder.SalesOrderId
)
group by l.Name
```

P.S.
Check also the dates columns, if they contains also time fraction you should reconsider your upper bound filter.

I suggest you to use `and SO_SalesOrder.OrderDate < '01-03-2018'` instead of <= 28-02